# How to control Pixhawk tracking color using DroneKit-python?

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I want to use Pixhawk to track a blue ball on the ground with a Raspberry Pi companion computer. 
But I found if I want to control Pixhawk, there's only 'SET_POSITION_TARGET_LOCAL_NED', in NED coordinate system.

1) In my color tracking program, I just want to move forward or move to the left/right by 1cm or 5cm, but 'SET_POSITION_TARGET_LOCAL_NED' expects a value in meters, and I need accuracy to smaller units.

2) My other question is could I control Pixhawk in body-frame coordinate system? Ned coordinate system could just control forward or left directly.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't matter that it is in meters, because the value that is sent is a float.  So you can send 0.01 to mean 1cm.
2. Yes, you can use body-frame.  This is an argument that is specified when sending `set_position_local_target_ned`.  Set argument 4 to `8`. Take a look at the mavlink spec for that message:

http://mavlink.org/messages/common#SET_POSITION_TARGET_LOCAL_NED